# Дублируются изображения в UITableView при прокрутке

Tags: ios, swift, vkontakte-api, uitableview, uiimage

Работаю с API VK. Сейчас нахожусь в стадии разработки стены. Возникла проблема при загрузке изображений. Стена представлена как UITableView где одна ячейка это пост. При прокручивании ленты дублируются изображения. Адекватного решения проблемы не нашел
Загружаю изображения внутри метода willDisplayCell, а не cellForRowAt, а сам код загрузки является асинхронным

```
func downloaded(from url: URL, contentMode mode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {  // for swift 4.2 syntax just use ===> mode: UIView.ContentMode
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.image = image
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Скорее всего где-то напутали с индексами. Как рассчитываете какая картинка к какой ячейке относится? И почему используете willDisplayCell вместо cellForRowAtIndexPath? willDisplay вызывается даже для тех ячеек, которые сейчас не видны, при этом он опционален для реализации, а cellForRowAtIndexPath обязателен. Покажите код для этих двух методов.

Comment: С индексами я точно не напутал. Когда кликаю на пост, он открывается в новом окне, но уже с правильной картинкой. Но а самом tableView картинки дублируются.

Comment: В cellForRowAt я создаю ячейку, а в willDisplayCell загружаю картинку. На самом деле я пытался все операции выполнить только в cellForRowAt, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Сами картинки вы где-то храните? Предположу, что нет, только присваиваете при загрузке нужной ячейке. Дублирование у вас идет из-за reuse ячейки, там сохраняется предыдущее состояние, пока нужная картинка подгружается асинхронно.

Comment: Да, я об этом думал. Не подскажете как это исправить?

Comment: Простейший вариант (вроде) - перенести код загрузки в cellForRowAtIndexPath (вызывается каждый раз, когда ячейка появляется на экране), в самом начале (т.е до загрузки картинки) добавить cell.currentImage= nil; По идее должно помочь, попробуйте. Но это довольно грубое решение, сейчас подумаю на решением получше.

Comment: Небольшое уточнение. У меня каждой в ячейке cell таблицы tableView содержится collectionView, куда собственно и загружаются изображения

Comment: CollectionView работает практически идентично таблице, там используете метод cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: Попробовал несколько способов, в том числе "в самом начале (т.е до загрузки картинки) добавить cell.currentImage= nil;" - не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Дублирование изображение в ячейках таблица/коллекции можно исправить использованием метода UITableViewCell/UICollectionViewCell (смотря где находится нужное UIImageView):

```
    override func prepareForReuse() {

        myImageView.image = nil
    }
```

Т.к. ячейки переиспользуются, то действительно может быть ситуация что одна и та же уже подгруженная картинка отображается в нескольких ячейках, поэтому стоит обнулять нужные поля в выше приведенном методе, который вызывается перед переиспользованием ячейки.
Надеюсь поможет!